# SQL Cast to show decimals

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

I have the following statement within my select clause;

```
(([Complt_Emp] + [No_Non_Complt_Emp])/ [No_of_Emp]) as Total_Completed
```

How do I implement CAST "cast(your_float_column as decimal(10,2))" ? I want my column Total_Completed to show 2 decimal places

I cannot seem to get the correct syntax!

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: a lot of times if each variable having calculations done on them are not decimal, you may have to cast all the ones not decimal to decimal before the calcualtions (so cast the no_of_emp as decilal, and assuming all the other ones already are, that may work, or you may have to cast the entire calcuation as decimal as well

Answer (score 2):

the result of the calculation depends of the used columns type.

If you divide int columns, you get int result  :  `1 / 6 = 0`

when you convert each values to decimal the result is: `1 / 6 = 0.1666666666666`

Now you want 2 decimal result,so you have to `convert`/ `round` the previous result to get the expected value

See fiddle for some example of divide and cast / round : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/51785/5

An easy trick can be to use :

```
round ( 1.0 * ( [Complt_Emp] + [No_Non_Complt_Emp] ) / [No_of_Emp] , 2 )
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect all your values are INT.    An int divided by an int will return an int.

```
(([Complt_Emp] + [No_Non_Complt_Emp])/ cast([No_of_Emp] as decimal(10,2)) as Total_Completed
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast each expression seperately

```
CAST(([Complt_Emp] + [No_Non_Complt_Emp]) as decimal(10,2)) /
CAST([No_of_Emp] as decimal(10,2)) as Total_Completed
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cast((([Complt_Emp] + [No_Non_Complt_Emp])/ [No_of_Emp]) as decimal(10,2)) as Total_Completed
```

Comment: This assumes you actually get a result from the algorithm, though.